# Is there a dstandard GP I/O port to control the onbord LED on Raspberry Pi RP2040-Zero? What port is it?

Tags: adafruit-circuitpython

Tried  without success to control the LED via board.led and board.led0 in CircuitPython.
Aso tried board.GP0 through board.GP29.
GP25 is in use and can't be programmed.

Comment: CircuitPython defines a standard name for the built-in LED for each board. I would try `led = DigitalInOut(board.LED)`and see if that works.  Maybe this discussion helps: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=336836

Comment: Also, the official docs, here: https://docs.circuitpython.org/en/latest/shared-bindings/digitalio/index.html

Comment: Hah! Never mind - I re-read your post and see you already used `board.LED`. I apologize for my nonsense.

Comment: Thank you Mike for trying to help with this.